# What is the difference in command-line "sudo apt-get update" and using Synaptic or Auto-updater?

Tags: command-line, updates, update-manager

The whole update process seems somewhat confusing to me.  I can understand the need to run `sudo apt-get update` prior to installing another package, but, what is the difference in running `update` from the **command-line** and using the **Synaptic** package manager for updates and/or the the **Auto-updater**.

If there is no difference, why do we have all three?

Comment: No difference. However, Synaptic is no longer installed by default, and the graphical Update Manager is not installed by default on servers. And on the other hand, GUIs are more convenient for most end users.

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get update` only updates your package list and does not perform an actual software update. To perform the actual update, you would need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after running `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` is run automatically in the back ground regularly. Auto-updater is the same as `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The pretty gui's use libraries that implement the same functions (they may be the same libraries), it's just a pretty gui for users to use. If you ask it to show you the details you'll notice they are just a slightly massaged version of the console output of apt-get.

Comment: I think both the GUIs use the `apt` Python libraries, not the actual command `apt-get` command.

Comment: You are probably correct. I'll correct my answer a bit to say it does the same thing, not uses the same binary.

Answer (score 0):

These are three types of methods given to the user.

1. Command line: manual
2. Synaptic and the Ubuntu Software Center: GUI (graphical user interface)
3. Auto-updater: automatic